# App Restarts on bringing it to foreground from different launch sources

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi I am stuck with this issue.
I have my app which has 3 activities:

SplashScreenActivity, LoginScreenActivity, ViewPagerActivity(which houses 3 fragments).
When I put the apk in the mobile sdcard and install and open using the packagemanager. My App starts up just fine.
Issue - But, now if I press the Home Button and again launch the app from the Apps drawer/Homescreen. The App seems to relaunch and I have to go through the entire flow of Splash and LoginScreen.

This issue does not occur if I launch the App the first time itself from the Apps drawer itself./If I long press the Home Button and select the App from recent apps list the app is resumed properly as well.

For Reference I launch activities using these flags

**Splash->Login**

```
Intent intent=new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

**LoginActivity->ViewPagerActivity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewPagerActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Home screen icon launches whatever activity you have declared as the `MAIN` ... `LAUNCHER` activity in your manifest. Generally, the launch activity in manifest should be the main activity of your app. From there you can invoke splash screens and login activities when needed.

Comment: To make this change I would end up having to save and restore Instance for every call to onPause(), where I would have to store my currently infocus activity/fragment details. My question is really about why does not the system just resume the App like it does in the other scenarios as mentioned in the question.

Comment: This is one of the ways to handle the scenario, hence accepting the answer. Although I found the root cause for the issue mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

remove these flags  or the complete line of code

`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue when launching with package manager.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2373

```
if (!isTaskRoot()) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && action != null && action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
```